# How is Gitlab different compared to Github?

Tags: github, gitlab

I'm trying to understand the pros and cons of the two from experienced developer's point of view. Of course Github is the more widely used of the two, but if someone could explain in general terms what they find better/lacking in either, that would be great.

(I use Github at the moment, by the way).

Comment: See https://about.gitlab.com/features/ and https://about.gitlab.com/comparison/

Comment: @MrTux that is a marketing page for Gitlab, and the exact reason why I wanted to ask developer's opinon. I Googled this topic already and didn't come up with any opinions given by developers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gitlab is a self-hosted git server. I have used both (plus bitbucket) and I don't see much difference in terms of functionality. Github's UI is far more advanced, and they offer some custom features (e.g. Releases).

Comment: Gitlab is also available as cloud/saas product.

Comment: Releases ar ealso possible with GitLab, just put a link or upload the file into the description box.

Comment: I have only used Gitlab for private repositories, so I might have missed some features. But in terms of CLI commands, I didn't notice any differences.

Comment: I've seen some people claim Bitbucket is way better than the other repository hosting services. I, for one, have only used GitHub. Can anyone with experience in both give his opinions about this claim?

Answer (score 2):

At Github , by default, you do not have any private repos ( ones only you and your team can access ). with Gitlab you have unlimited of them.

Edit: as pointed out by  Bahman.A in the comments, this is no longer true

Comment: This answer is old, Github does give you private repo now!